# I get the same object twice

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to get all the lessons of the students that have a grade that contains a certain term.

The orange relations are the relevant relations:
[image: The orange relations are the relevant relations]

The query:

```
SELECT 
tg.nhsColor AS cellColor,
tg.nhsTgradeName AS LessonName,
lsons.nhsLessonID AS LessonID,
lsons.nhsTgradeID AS TgradeID,
lsons.nhsDay AS nhsDay,
lsons.nhsHour AS nhsHour,
tg.nhsTeacherID AS TeacherID
FROM 
nhsTeacherGrades AS tg,
nhsLessons AS lsons,
nhsLearnGroups,
nhsMembers AS mem,
nhsGrades AS grd 
WHERE 
tg.nhsTgradeID = lsons.nhsTgradeID 
AND nhsLearnGroups.nhsTgradeID = tg.nhsTgradeID 
AND mem.nhsUserID = nhsLearnGroups.nhsStudentID
AND mem.nhsGradeID = grd.nhsGradeID 
AND grd.nhsGradeName LIKE '%"+gradePart+"%'
```

The query works, yet, i get the same lesson twice from this query.

Comment: an quick and unsatisfying way is to add DISTINCT to the beginning of the SELECT list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get duplicates for at least two reasons:

- the same lessons can occur in different teacher grades followed by a certain student
- different students can follow the same teacher grade

The following (untested) nested SQL could solve this. It gets the teacher grade ID of each lesson and checks which of these have at least one viable student linked to it:

```
SELECT     tg.nhsColor AS cellColor,
           tg.nhsTgradeName AS LessonName,
           lsons.nhsLessonID AS LessonID,
           lsons.nhsTgradeID AS TgradeID,
           lsons.nhsDay AS nhsDay,
           lsons.nhsHour AS nhsHour,
           tg.nhsTeacherID AS TeacherID
FROM       nhsLessons AS lsons
INNER JOIN nhsTeacherGrades AS tg 
        ON tg.nhsTgradeID = lsons.nhsTgradeID
WHERE      tg.nhsTgradeID IN (
              SELECT     grp.nhsTgradeID
              FROM       (nhsLearnGroups grp
              INNER JOIN nhsMembers AS mem 
                      ON mem.nhsUserID = grp.nhsStudentID)
              INNER JOIN nhsGrades AS grd
                      ON mem.nhsGradeID = grd.nhsGradeID 
              WHERE      grd.nhsGradeName LIKE '%"+gradePart+"%' 
           )
```

Note that I used the `JOIN` syntax, which is considered better practice than placing join conditions in the `WHERE` clause. MS Access is quite pesky about using parentheses in the `JOIN` clauses, so you might need to play with those a bit to make it work.

Comment: Thank you sir. I was about to break my head on the wall. Thank you!